# After filtering subscribing data, need to get initial data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have filtered Observable, but when i am trying again by different method, i get empty field.

`filterProjLessThenThree(){`

`this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(map(projects => this.projects.filter(project => project.id > 5))) .subscribe(response => this.projects = response);}`

After filtering once, i need to get initial date for filtering again by different methods. Any ideas how to reset to the previous one?

`filterProjBeetwenThreeAndFive(){`

`this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(map(projects => this.projects.filter(project => project.id >= 3 && project.id < 5))).subscribe(response => this.projects = response);}`

Comment: There are many way to do this. For instance you can use pairwise (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) to keep old and new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Observable.
Use the share operator to avoid duplication.
And now, create 2 subscribers:

```
 projects$=this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(share());

  filterProjLessThenThree(){
  this.projects$.pipe(
    map(projects => projects.filter(project => project.id > 5))
  ).subscribe(response => this.projects = response);
  }


  filterProjBeetwenThreeAndFive(){

  this.projects$.pipe(
    map(projects => projects.filter(project => project.id >= 3 && project.id < 5))
   ).subscribe(response => this.projects = response);
  }
```

Tip1:
Instead of filtering inside a map operator
Use the filter operator:

```
  this.projects$.pipe(
    switchMap(list=>list),
    filter(item=> item.id>=3 &&item.id<5),
    toArray()
  ).subscribe(response => this.projects = response);
```

Tip2:
Do not forget Unsbscribe! Or best, use `async` pipe

Comment: Thank you. I get and tested. Works fine!

Comment: @AlexBeria If that helped, I'd be happy if you voted